# Why isn't my Popup within style with an included TooltipService working correctly?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, popup, tooltip, styles

I have two radio buttons I need the stylized popup to work on and adding the ToolTipService to one, fixes the Popup's functionality on both (each has its own style).

So the description. I have copy/pasted a popup we are using elsewhere in the project (also on a different type of radio button style) and put them into the styles for the buttons I am currently working on. I now can be sure the popup works where it currently is because if I add a tooltipservice to the borders defined within the style, it fixes functionality. (also if I remove the popup tags and just leave it as a grid it will show up too).

The easiest solution I can think of is to ask this. Is there a way to make a ToolTipService that is invisible/collapsed to enable the fix?

Barring that here is the code I am working with and maybe someone can answer the real issue. It has been chopped up for your viewing pleasure

```
<Style x:Key="VisualViewRadioButtonLeftStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseLRRadioButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.3" Value="0"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.5" Value="1"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.4" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="Normal1" >
                            <Image Source="picture" Style="{StaticResource VisualViewRadioButtonImageStyle}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Popup Opacity="0" IsOpen="True" IsHitTestVisible="False" >
                        <Grid x:Name="grid"  Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" >
                            <Path x:Name="path2" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Data="M1.9999998,3.9790393E-13" UseLayoutRounding="False" >
                            </Path>
                            <TextBlock Text="Chart" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If I were to add a ToolTipService to the Border named "Normal1" it would fix both this button and the style below it (they are placed next to eachother).

I have also tried re-locating the position where I define the popup.

The two radio buttons are then added to a stackpanel to display them. The small code section is below.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Tabs" x:Name="TopContent1" Style="{StaticResource VisualViewRadioButtonLeftStyle}" />
        <RadioButton GroupName="Tabs" x:Name="TopContent2List" Style="{StaticResource VisualViewRadioButtonRightStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent" Content="{Binding MainContentTopSelected}"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I put your code in an empty SL4 project and it seems to work fine, except for the fact that the tooltips are only showed once. Is that the problem that you are facing? Also, why don't you just use ToolTipService.ToolTip? Is it because you want to control the animation speed?

Comment: @alfonso I guess its less apparent after the code is hacked up but that popup has a specific stylized design that we are using in another place that we want to re-use. Essentially we would have this nice interface and then an ugly plain tooltip over some buttons, and I'd prefer to avoid that. I'll try and update with more information that might be relevant

Comment: Does anyone know of anything that can interfere with a Popup that perhaps I'm not showing? Any information is appreciated.